# syntax error on linking table

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am having some troubles with a linking table.
I am getting an "Error: near "BookName": syntax error" from the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE word_book (
WordName TEXT(25), FOREIGN KEY (WordName) REFERENCES word (WordName)
BookName TEXT(25), FOREIGN KEY (BookName) REFERENCES book (BookName)
PRIMARY KEY (WordName, BookName));
```

I was able to successfully create the tables `book` and `word`. The `book` table contains the column `BookName` and the table `word` contains the column `WordName`.

Answer (score 0):

This statement lacks the commas after the FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Furthermore, SQL requires that all table constraints come after all columns.

Either reorder them:

```
CREATE TABLE word_book (
    WordName TEXT(25),
    BookName TEXT(25),
    FOREIGN KEY (WordName) REFERENCES word (WordName),
    FOREIGN KEY (BookName) REFERENCES book (BookName),
    PRIMARY KEY (WordName, BookName)
);
```

Or use column constraints instead:

```
CREATE TABLE word_book (
    WordName TEXT(25) REFERENCES word (WordName),
    BookName TEXT(25) REFERENCES book (BookName),
    PRIMARY KEY (WordName, BookName)
);
```